# Search string and store value next to it in variable in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-shell

I have requirement to read a text file and search for a string and store the value next to searched string in a variable.
I have to store each occurrence of value in a variable.

So my text file will be:

> hello
>
> how are you
>
> my number is: 1
>
> your number:
>
> I am good
>
> I an fine
>
> my number is: 234
>
> your number:

so i have to search string "my number is" and store the 1 in a variable and then value 234 in same variable with comma(,) separated variable.

Note: string "my number is" can be repetitive multiple times and i have to store all its value.

My ultimate goal will be to store each comma separated values in temp table.

Please provide your suggestions.

My attempted code:

```
for /f "tokens=4* delims= " %%a in ('findstr "my number is" "C:\test.txt"') do set "line=%%a"
echo "%line%
```

Comment: Why _put on hold_? IMHO,  the OP's question is clear enough. I have an answer ready to post...

Comment: A suggestion at least: 1. `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion`; 2. `set "line="`; 3. `for ... findstr /IC:"my number is" ... do set "line=!line!,%%a"`; 4. `echo %line:~1%`

Comment: Thanks a lot JosefZ. Your seggestion work perfectly for given input file.Now i have a different requirement, please check that and provide suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome. For a different requirement: just ask another question... Read and follow  [ask] to prevent putting on hold...

Answer (score 1):

```
line=$(fgrep "my number is" test.txt | sed "s/[^0-9]//g" | tr '\n' ',' | sed "s/,$//")
```

- `line=$(...)` sets output of ... to `$line`
- `fgrep` returns all lines containing `my number is`
- first `sed` removes all non-digit characters (modify regex accordingly if you're expecting negative or floating-point numbers)
- `tr` joins all lines, delimiting them with `,`
- second `sed` removes the trailing comma

Comment: Good answer, but I believe dude wants something for windows, hence the batch-file tag.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I am looking for answer in Batch script.Please let me know how to achive this in Batch script. I will use this script in Windows 2008 R2.